# Application wont run after Install NSIS

Tags: syntax, nsis

I wrote an Installer my first script, after it installs the application it wont run in win 10 it throws an error. I have to copy over the backup exe file to the applications dir then it runs. Was thinking it might have to do with file permissions although i have no idea how to fix it. Running installer as admin. Has anyone encountered this problem? My folder in programfiles isn't being deleted when uninstalled, but that's a different problem.

```html
;Installer v1
SetCompressor /SOLID lzma


!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MUI_ICON "C:\Users\Crash\Pictures\Fry.ico"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "C:\Users\Crash\Pictures\kin.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
;--------------------------------


; The name of the installer
Name "blabla"

; The file to write
OutFile "blabla.exe"

; The default installation directory
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\"

; Registry key to check for directory (so if you install again, it will 
; overwrite the old one automatically)
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\blabla" "Install_Dir\blabla"

; Request application privileges for Windows Vista
RequestExecutionLevel admin

;--------------------------------
;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  
;pages
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "C:\Users\Crash\Desktop\NSIS installer\Extract\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
  
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
  

  
;--------------------------------
;Languages
 
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; The stuff to install
Section "blabla (required)"

  SectionIn RO
  
  ; Set output path to the installation directory.
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  
  ; Put file there
  File /r "C:\games\blabla*"
  
  ; Write the installation path into the registry
  WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\blabla "Install_Dir" "$INSTDIR"
  
  ; Write the uninstall keys for Windows
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\blabla" "DisplayName" "blabla"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\blabla" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"'
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\blabla" "NoModify" 1
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\blabla" "NoRepair" 1
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\blabla\uninstall.exe"
  
SectionEnd

; Optional section (can be disabled by the user)
Section "Start Menu Shortcuts"

  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\blabla"
  CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\blabla\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\blabla\uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" 0
  CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\blabla\blabla.lnk" "$INSTDIR\blabla\blabla.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\blabla\blabla.exe" 0
  
SectionEnd

Section "Creat Desktop Shortcut?" SectionX
    SetShellVarContext current
    CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\blabla.lnk" "$INSTDIR\blabla\blabla.exe"
SectionEnd

  Section "Extract Data Files 11.3gb"
  SectionIn RO
  FileOpen $4 "$INSTDIR\blabla\Extract.bat" w
  FileWrite $4 "$\"$INSTDIR\blabla\7zip\7za.exe$\" x $\"$EXEDIR\Extract\Extract.7z.001$\" -o$\"$INSTDIR\blabla\$\" -aoa"
  FileClose $4
  Goto Runbat
  Runbat:
   File /nonfatal "INSTDIR\blabla\Extract.bat"
    ExecWait "$INSTDIR\blabla\Extract.bat"
 SectionEnd
 



;--------------------------------

; Uninstaller

Section "Uninstall"
  
  ; Remove registry keys
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\blabla"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\blabla"

  ; Remove files and uninstaller
  Delete "$INSTDIR\blabla\blabla.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\blabla\uninstall.exe"

  ; Remove shortcuts, if any
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\blabla\*.*"
  Delete "$DESKTOP\blabla.lnk"

  ; Remove directories used
  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\blabla"
  RMDir /r "$INSTDIR\blabla"

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

"InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\"" here is the problem turns out that just the shortcut wouldn't work. Was trying to avoid correcting the installDir as you probably can see in the code. Perhaps this would solve my uninstaller problem aswell.